# how to define min(|H|,|G|) of intersection distance of histograms

Tags: histogram, distance

I search lots of materials about intersection distance, however still confuse about the denominator [image] what is the magnitude of histogram? somep paper said sum of samples, in that case  if h image is 20x20 pixel, g is 800*600 pixel .. In that case min(|h|,|G|) is equal to |H| in most case? am i right?

Answer (score 0):

the h,g histogram is normalized histogram, for l2 normalization min(|h|,|g|) is 1, but for l2 normalization (also called vector normalization) the denominator is  min(|h|,|g|).